# C# equivalent of VB.NET "Imports <xmlns>" XML schema

Tags: c#, vb.net, xml-namespaces

I have an old VB.NET web application project that I'm converting to C#. I've converted the majority of the app using SharpDevelop but have run into an issue converting some special case code:

```
' Namespace
Imports <xmlns:items="urn:list_items">

' Code:
Dim group = From items In ListItems...<items:item> _
                 Where items.<item.name> = "Something"
                 Select names = items.<item.name>
```

I am not aware of the C# equivalent of VB.NET's method of using XML schemas. Is there a way of importing the schema and using the same LINQ statements?

Edit:

The part that threw me through a loop was the conversion (by way of SharpDevelop) of `Imports <xmlns:items="urn:list_items">` to `using urn:list_items`. The compiler complains about this syntax.

I was just curious if there was a C# equivalent of the directive to import the XML schema and use it as part of the LINQ queries, but given that C# doesn't support XML literals in the same way VB.NET does, it is not relevant.

Comment: Please post more of the code, including the XML, so we can determine what you're actually asking.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: The ellipses means "descendant".  http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2010/08/31/xml-literals-reading-an-xml-file-with-a-namespace.aspx.  The Linq statement seems pretty self-explanatory; I'm assuming that it actually works.

Comment: @Paperjam: In any case, you can't use the Linq statements *as they are currently written.*  The ellipses are a VB.NET feature, not supported in C#.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I was thrown through a loop on the compiler error for the `Imports` conversion (translates as `using urn:list_items`) so I had a hard time posing the question. I think @RobertHarvey is right: there's no way to use the VB.NET LINQ statements as written, and as such using the schema via a directive is not relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no equivalent. C# has no support for XML literals.

---

C# does support LINQ to XML. However, the code you posted is the special VB.NET syntax that allows both the XML and the processing of the XML to be specified in a form much closer to actual XML. C# has no equivalent of this.

---

If you're not actually looking for an equivalent, but only a translation, then maybe the following:

```
XNamespace itemsNs = "urn:list_items";
var group = from items in ListItems.Descendants(itemsNs + "item")
            where items.Element("item").Element("name").Value == "Something"
            select new
                {
                    names = items.Element("item").Element("name").Value
                };
```